# Cannot find virtualenvwrapper after installing

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I installed virtualenvwrapper like this:

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

I thought I would find it here:

```
/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

but I did not.

I am trying to configure it in bashrc.

Where can I find it?

Comment: if you run `pip freeze` does `virtualenvwrapper` appear in the list?

Comment: @Railslide, I uninstalled and reinstalled virtualenvwrapper and it helped. But I ran into another problem: when I try to `mkvirtualenv` it is saying `No module named stevedore` any ideas?

Comment: There are several questions about that error. Try to run a search and see of any of the suggested solutions solves your problem